# What's the formulation of this elements?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying  to find  the formulation of these elements.

$N$ is a constant.

$a_k=1$

$a_{k-1} =a_k* \frac{k-1}{N}$

$a_{k-2}  = a_{k-1} * \frac{k-2}{N}$

$a_{k-3} =a_{k-2} * \frac{(k-3)}{N}$

.

.

$a_2=\frac{2*a_3}{N}$

$a_1=\frac{a_2}{N}$

By placing the values , I got the formula, but it's not true. Where is my mistake?

For every $ k' : (1<= k' <= k)$

$a_k'=\frac{(k-1)!}{(2k-(k'-1))!  *(N^{k-k'})}$

Comment: What is the pattern in the subscripts on $a$ in right sides? from second formula you now have these as $k,k-2,k-2,..$ -- maybe should be $k,k-1,k-2$ decrease by 1 each time?

Comment: Hi @coffeemath . yes. I wrote it wrong. I edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are looking for is
$$
a_j = \frac{(k-1)!}{(j-1)!} N^{j-k} .
$$

In fact:

- $a_k=1$,
- $a_j = \frac{j}{N}\frac{(k-1)!}{(j+1-1)!}N^{j+1-k} = \frac{j}{N}a_{j+1}$.

Comment: Hi @Federico Thanks a lot!